# Syntax help in session sql query

Tags: sql, syntax, asp-classic

In an CLASSIC ASP page, I have 2 session variables (session_1) & (session_2).
I want to retrieve data from an sql database table, that contests are equals to the above sessions.
For example:

```
select * from table.xxx WHERE field.xxx = session_1 AND field.fff = session_2
```

I need help for the correct syntax of the above query

Comment: You need to add the _values_ of the session variable to the query. Please [edit] and add the actual code, all you will need to do would be to concatenate the values to the query (with quotes around the string values).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm *guessing* you're just executing a sql statement instead of using [parameterized queries](https://vikaskanani.wordpress.com/2012/05/07/classic-asp-sql-injection-prevention-by-using-query-parameter/), in which case you would have something like:

```
sql = "select * from table.xxx......."
```

now, in your example above, you have:

```
WHERE field.xxx = session_1 AND field.fff = session_2
```

the same field cannot contain 2 values in one record, as you are suggesting by using the AND keyword, so it should look like:

```
WHERE field.xxx = session_1 OR field.fff = session_2
```

now we want to get the actual session variables into the sql string you want to execute:

```
sql = "select * from table.xxx WHERE field.xxx = '" & Session("session_1") & "' OR field.fff = '" & Session("session_2") & "'"
```

I strongly recommend using [parameterized queries](https://vikaskanani.wordpress.com/2012/05/07/classic-asp-sql-injection-prevention-by-using-query-parameter/) to sanitize your data and prevent [sql injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), but for now, to understand the basics, this should get you going in the right direction.

Comment: '" & Session("session_1") & "'  -  That’s all a needed. It works! Thanks for your advice to use parameterized queries, but I don’t need them in the specific project…